# SaveChangesAsync not saving a specific value when it's assigned

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework-core, guid

I've ran into an issue I can't quite seem to figure out. Here I have a ticket item which is assigned to user. I have implemented a feature to be able to change the user. The user is changed and updated correctly however, the `UserID` value for the ticket remains unchanged despite being reassigned and `SaveChangesAsync` being called to confirm these changes. `.AssignedUser` is changed in the database and saved however, the `UserID` refuses to update in the db. None of the values are null and when setting a breakpoint and running through the function it all seems to assign itself correctly with the correct values. The value `UserID` just does not save or update. Would appreciate any insight into this. Thanks in advance

### Ticket model

```
public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Guid UserID { get; set; } //who the ticket is assigned to

    public Guid CreatedByUser { get; set; } //who this ticket is created by

    public ApplicationUser CreatedBy { get; set; } //created by user
    
    public ApplicationUser AssignedUser { get; set; } // who the ticket is assigned to

}
```

### Razor page

```
[Parameter] public Guid Id { get; set; }
private Ticket ticketItem { get; set; } = new Ticket();
private ApplicationUser AssignUser { get; set; } = new ApplicationUser();

private async Task ChangeUser()
{

try
{
    var response = await Http.PutAsJsonAsync($"Tickets/changeuser/{AssignUser.UserName}/{ticketItem.Id}", AssignUser);

} catch(Exception) { ... }

}
```

### Controller making the changes

```
    [HttpPut("changeuser/{username}/{ticketID}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ChangeTicketUser(string username, Guid ticketID)
    {
        ApplicationUser findUser;
        Ticket ticketItem;
        try {
            findUser = await _userManager.Users.FirstAsync(u => u.Email.Equals(username));
            
        } catch (Exception)
        {
            return Forbid(); //user not found
        }

        try
        {
            ticketItem = await _context.Tickets.Where(t => t.Id.ToString().Equals(ticketID.ToString())).FirstAsync();
        } catch (Exception)
        {
            return BadRequest(); //ticket not found
        }


        ticketItem.AssignedUser = findUser;
        ticketItem.UserID = Guid.Parse(findUser.Id);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return NoContent();

    }
```

### Values are different and valid

[image]

### Requested ApplicationUser Model

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }

    public string lastName { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastAccessed { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to "Parse" a value for a user id that is literally another user id? They should be the same datatype, shouldn't they?

Comment: Why don't you just compare the fields? `_contedt.Tickets.Where(t=>t.Id==ticketID)`. And if `Id` is the key, you can use `var ticketItem=_context.Tickets.Find(ticketId);`

Comment: Identity uses a string type while I decided to use a Guid

Comment: What is with all the "ToString"s anyway? A Guid can be compared to another Guid using == as normal.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you use `ToString()` all over the place. Unless `Id` is a string, you're effectively disabling the index on `Id` and end up scanning the entire table

Comment: If you use `FirstOrDefaultAsync` you'll avoid the *expensive* exception

Comment: Oh right. I will make those changes. But would those fix UserID and make it update?

Comment: Can you post your user model and how user and ticket are linked? I have a hard time even understanding why your code *compiles*. Why do you have different datatypes in the primary key table and in the foreign key table for the same field? That should not work. At all.

Comment: Sure I will add my ApplicationUser model

Comment: Where in your database model are UserId and AssignedUser linked?

Comment: @nvoigt Thanks for the reply. I am not sure what you mean by linked, they're both in the Tickets model. UserID is assigned manually using the AssignedUser object. This is done primarily to make searching easier.

Comment: It seems this started to work momentarily when I had a breakpoint set on the controller function. However, removing the breakpoint and testing again, it stopped working. Re-adding the breakpoint also did not help, it's returned to it's original state of not updating the value. Very weird.

Comment: did you test _context.Tickets.Update(ticketItem);  before savechange?

Comment: @foadabdollahi I have just tried this. Did not seem to work either.

Comment: Turn on logging and you can see the queries sent to the database.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging  Sometimes this happens because you're not connecting to the database you think you are.

Comment: I mean that somewhere, you told EF that "UserID" is the field to use to figure out what to load as "AssignedUser" navigation property, right? How else would that entity be saved?